# How to change JSON into string

Tags: javascript, json

i got a words array in JSON form like:

```
var words = [];
words.push({word:"I",x:50,y:50});
```

and i want it to store into a txt file which user can download from the website.

```
...
var data = JSON.stringify(words);
var file = new Blob([data],{type:'plain/text'});
...
```

however the output file is like this:

```
{"word":"Peaceful","x":40,"y":65,"lyric":"lyric"}
```

but i want it only print out the word "peaceful", i tried to use

```
var data = JSON.stringify(words.word);
```

but the output shows undefined.

Comment: why not `new Blob([words[0].word],{type:'plain/text'})`?

Comment: Just so it's said...JSON **is** a string. That's the entire point of it: to represent hierarchical data as text.

Comment: JSON is a string

Comment: The output file should be like `[{"word":"Peaceful","x":40,"y":65,"lyric":"lyric"}]`, not what you showed.

Answer (score 0):

`words` is an array, so you have to index it to access the object that you pushed onto it:

```
var data = JSON.stringify(words[0].word);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly.

```
var myWords = [];

(for var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
   var word = words[i].word;

   myWords.push(word);
}

myWords.join(' '); // or myWords.join('\n');
```